# Grading Scale in Python Without Decision Statements

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program in python 3 that will take a percentage score and print out the letter grade based on the grading scale 90-100:A,80-89:B,70-79:C,60-69:D,<60:F using strings and lists

```
#gradeScale.py
#This program takes a percent score and tells the user what letter grade it is based on the grading scale

def main():
    print("This program takes a percent score and tells the user what letter grade it is based on the grading scale")
    gradingScale = ["F","F","F","F","F","F","F","D","C","B","A"]
    grade = eval(input("Please enter the percent score: "))


main()
```

Comment: It's ok that this is a hw question, but please show us your attempt to answer this question first.

Comment: @rbierman This is some of the code that was trying to work with: gradingScale = ["F","F","F","F","F","F","F","D","C","B","A"] What I was trying to do was somehow use rounding to access the characters in the list. It wasn't working too well, so I scrapped that idea

Comment: Please edit your question to include actual code that you've written. (and please don't post this code as a comment)

Comment: You might want to look into `range` and `dict` objects, if you can't use `if`, `elif`, and `else` statements. A `dict` value --> key lookup looks like what you need.

Comment: @not_a_robot I can only use the skills that we've learned in class so far (loops, graphics, lists, strings, some of the math library, and other extremely basic things like print statements) and range and dict are not some of the things that we have learned. Thanks for the advice thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for using magic out of Hogwarts but:

```
grades = 'FEDCBA'
score = int(input('Enter your score: '))
grade = ((score // 10) - 4) * (score // 50) * (100 // (score + 1)) + (score // 100) * 5
print('Grade is', grades[grade])
```

works from 0 to 199 (90-199 is an A)

I'll try to explain 3rd line.

`(score // 10) - 4)` helps us find grade from 50 to 99 as index in `grades` string.

`* (score // 50)` makes all scores from 0 to 49 evaluate to `0` (index of 'F')

`* (100 // (score + 1)) + (score // 100) * 5` makes all scores from 100 to 199 evaluate to 5 (index of 'A')

Comment: Could you supply an explanation of what's going on in line 3 for future readers?

Comment: @not_a_robot hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a great start:

```
gradingScale = ["F", "F", "F" , "F" , "F" , "F", "F", "D", "C", "B", "A"]
```

This is a list of 11 letter grades. Your scores range from 0 to 100. How might you map a range of 101 possible grades (0 to 100) to those items? Maybe by dividing by 10 and throwing away the remainder:

```
print(gradingScale[grade // 10])
```

This doesn't work quite right though: 70 should be a C but comes out as D. 99 should be an A but comes out as B. Only 100 comes out as A when 90-100 should be A.

The answer here is that there are two "bins" of 10 that should be an A. 90-99, and 100-109 (although we will only use 100 out of that bin). So, we just need to shift things down: take one of the Fs off the start and add an A to the end of the grading scale:

```
gradingScale = ["F", "F" , "F" , "F" , "F", "F", "D", "C", "B", "A", "A"]
```

And now it works!

To simplify the code a little, we can take advantage of the fact that the letter grades are single characters, and also that strings can be indexed like lists (you get a single character) and so `gradingScale` can just be a simple string:

```
gradingScale = "FFFFFFDCBAA"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a string and just look up the grade by index.

```
grades = ("F" * 60) + ("D" * 10) + ("C" * 10) + ("B" * 10) + ("A" * 11)

def get_grade(score):
    return grades[score]

def main():
    print("This program takes a percent score and tells the user what letter grade it is based on the grading scale")
    grade = get_grade(input("Please enter the percent score: "))
    print(grade)

main()
```

Comment: creative, but certainly not the best way around the problem. It has next to no flexibility. I would think that this answer could be improved significantly.

Comment: I like this --- a more precise variant of [kindall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40644736/4116239).  It could easily be adapted to in-between grades like C- and B+ by varying the `grades` string.  You might want to rename `eval` to something that's not already a builtin, though...  I get queasy when I see `eval(anything)`, even though I know _your_ `eval` is some other function.  Maybe call it `grade_score` or `graded`?  (It's frustrating that the verb and noun forms of "grade" are the same.)

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Okay, since this is apparently a homework assignment, and you have only learned these topics so far ("loops, graphics, lists, strings, some of the math library, and other extremely basic things like print statements"), we will try something else.

**I will leave this answer here in case you want to come back and study it once you've learned about dictionaries, but see the answers of @kindall and @Yevhen Kuzmovych below! Good work thus far.**

As I alluded to in the comments, since you can't use `if`, `elif`, or `else` control flow statements, it looks like a `dict` lookup should suit you:

```
def main():
    grades = {'A': range(90, 101), 'B': range(80, 90), 'C': range(70, 80), 'D': range(60, 70), 'F': range(0, 60)}
    grade = eval(input("Please enter the percent score: "))
    return [letter for letter, rnge in grades.items() if grade in rnge][0]
```

Breaking it down:

```
grades = {'A': range(90, 101), 'B': range(80, 90), 'C': range(70, 80), 'D': range(60, 70), 'F': range(0, 60)}
```

This is a dictionary, in which your designated letter grades are keys and their respective upper and lower bounds are `range` objects.

```
[letter for letter, rnge in grades.items() if grade in rnge][0]
```

This is a list comprehension, in which we iterate through each (key, value) tuple in the list returned by `grades.items()` and see if the submitted grade falls in the range of a given letter grade. Since there is no overlap in the ranges, this list will have one element. The `[0]` indexing at the end allows us to return `str` instead of a `list`.

Try it:

```
>>> main()
Please enter the percent score: 80
'B'
```

Comment: There's an `if` in that thar list comprehension... I think that would violate the spirit of the assignment if not the letter.

Comment: Fair enough. Didn't notice. Will have to think of something else. That would probably require just a dictionary of 101 key: value pairs... One for each percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Illustrating a program that provides a grade for a score:

```
def main():
    print "Provides a grade as per the range of marks"
    score=input("Enter the exam score: ")

    gr="FFFFFFDCBAA"
    pos=gr[score/10]
    print "The grade obtained is: ",pos

main()
```